# Getting 404 - not found when attempting to add files over 20MB to SharePoint via SPWeb

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, asmx

Strange deal. We've set the config of the asmx service to allow file sizes up to 70MB like so:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="70000"/>
```

And everything works until you attempt a file file over 20MB. The exception that is making it up the stack is

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not
>   Found.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.InvokeAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

This is the block of code from the asmx that attempts to place the file in the directory/collection:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string UploadFile(byte[] contents, string destUrl)
        {
            var theReturn = "Bad";

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();

                site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);
            });

            theReturn = "Good";

            return theReturn;
        }
```

We suspect that it might have to do with a max file size constraint on the SharePoint side, but we're having trouble locating that setting or finding any documentation on it. Although, it could obviously be something else. I'm looking for ideas. TIA

Comment: Check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/tfsadmin/thread/b3cee101-1f6f-4c1c-a28d-71b393063894 for how to view and set your max file size on sharepoint. I don't see an immediate issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the max file upload in the web application general settings ?

[image]

You should also have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083 to ensure you made all relevant changes.

Comment: Yep. It's actually set to 500MB. I'll try to check into some of the other things listed in the kb